# Proper way to write a value for an attribute whose name is in a variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

Lots of searching here and around suggested that you could use a second argument to send() to write a value to an attribute, but in Rails 4 you are told you have the wrong number of parameters:

```
> prj = Project.where(:id => 123).first
> fieldname = "project_start_date"
> prj.send(fieldname, Date.today)
ArgumentError : wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
```

That approach was thought to be synonymous with

```
> prj.write_attribute(fieldname, Date.today)
```

But that errors with

```
NoMethodError : private method `write_attribute'
```

which is odd since the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Write.html#method-i-write_attribute) say this is a part of the instance public methods.

The ActiveRecord docs suggest using the class [update](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-update) method:

```
# Updates one record
Person.update(15, user_name: 'Samuel', group: 'expert')

# Updates multiple records
people = { 1 => { "first_name" => "David" }, 2 => { "first_name" => "Jeremy" } }
Person.update(people.keys, people.values)
So what's a Rails 4 guy supposed to do?
```

In my case that would translate to:

```
Project.update(123, project_start_date: '2013/09/04') #not using variables for testing sake
```

and that yields me a nice:

```
 ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  zero-length delimited identifier at or near """"
LINE 1: ...dual".* FROM "project"  WHERE "project"."" = $1 LI...
```

So what's a Rails 4 user supposed to use, other than writing out the actual SQL statements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close in your first example. The reason send isn't working is because you're essentially trying to do:

```
prj.project_start_date(Date.today)
```

which doesn't make sense because the project_start_date method does not take an argument. You need to change it to the setter

```
prj.project_start_date = Date.today
```

which would translate to:

```
prj.send("#{fieldname}=", Date.today)
```

Comment: Thank you for uncrossing my eyeballs on this one!